# Julia in Jupyter: kernel error ("Failed to precompile in IJulia")

Tags: jupyter-notebook, julia, jupyter

Having added Julia to Jupyter, I encounter the following problem:

[image]

I wonder if there is a fix for this? For example, by changing the path to `\.julia` to a local drive (`C:\` in my case is in fact not).

```
Julia Version 1.2.0
Commit c6da87ff4b (2019-08-20 00:03 UTC)
Platform Info:
  OS: Windows (x86_64-w64-mingw32)
  CPU: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E3-1284L v4 @ 2.90GHz
  WORD_SIZE: 64
  LIBM: libopenlibm
  LLVM: libLLVM-6.0.1 (ORCJIT, broadwell)
```

```
julia> Pkg.status()
    Status `C:\Users\xxxxxx\.julia\environments\v1.2\Project.toml`
  [7073ff75] IJulia v1.21.1
```

EDIT: actually typing `using IJulia` in the command line returns:

```
julia> using IJulia
[ Info: Precompiling IJulia [7073ff75-c697-5162-941a-fcdaad2a7d2a]
ERROR: LoadError: Blosc not installed properly, run Pkg.build("ZMQ"), restart Ju
lia and try again
Stacktrace:
 [1] error(::String) at .\error.jl:33
 [2] top-level scope at C:\Users\xxxxxxx\.julia\packages\ZMQ\ItfqT\src\ZMQ.jl:14

 [3] include at .\boot.jl:328 [inlined]
 [4] include_relative(::Module, ::String) at .\loading.jl:1094
 [5] include(::Module, ::String) at .\Base.jl:31
 [6] top-level scope at none:2
 [7] eval at .\boot.jl:330 [inlined]
 [8] eval(::Expr) at .\client.jl:432
 [9] top-level scope at .\none:3
in expression starting at C:\Users\xxxxxxx\.julia\packages\ZMQ\ItfqT\src\ZMQ.jl:
13
ERROR: LoadError: Failed to precompile ZMQ [c2297ded-f4af-51ae-bb23-16f91089e4e1
] to C:\Users\xxxxxxx\.julia\compiled\v1.2\ZMQ\CaaO6.ji.
Stacktrace:
 [1] error(::String) at .\error.jl:33
 [2] compilecache(::Base.PkgId, ::String) at .\loading.jl:1253
 [3] _require(::Base.PkgId) at .\loading.jl:1013
 [4] require(::Base.PkgId) at .\loading.jl:911
 [5] require(::Module, ::Symbol) at .\loading.jl:906
 [6] include at .\boot.jl:328 [inlined]
 [7] include_relative(::Module, ::String) at .\loading.jl:1094
 [8] include(::Module, ::String) at .\Base.jl:31
 [9] top-level scope at none:2
 [10] eval at .\boot.jl:330 [inlined]
 [11] eval(::Expr) at .\client.jl:432
 [12] top-level scope at .\none:3
in expression starting at C:\Users\xxxxxxx\.julia\packages\IJulia\yLI42\src\IJul
ia.jl:36
ERROR: Failed to precompile IJulia [7073ff75-c697-5162-941a-fcdaad2a7d2a] to C:\
Users\xxxxxxx\.julia\compiled\v1.2\IJulia\nfu7T.ji.
Stacktrace:
 [1] error(::String) at .\error.jl:33
 [2] compilecache(::Base.PkgId, ::String) at .\loading.jl:1253
 [3] _require(::Base.PkgId) at .\loading.jl:1013
 [4] require(::Base.PkgId) at .\loading.jl:911
 [5] require(::Module, ::Symbol) at .\loading.jl:906
```

Comment: Please post the output of: `julia> versioninfo(); using Pkg; Pkg.status()`

Comment: In general try `]up` or if that fails try `]activate ijulia-test; ]add IJulia` and try again

Comment: I'm confused, in the picture you are using Julia 1.1, below your are using Julia 1.2. Which one is it?

Answer (score 2):

My working solution:

1. `rm -rfd ~/.julia/compiled`
2. In the julia REPL:

   `using Pkg`

   `Pkg.update()`

   `Pkg.precompile()`
3. Assuming we previously installed / updated `IJulia`, then from Julia REPL:

   `using IJulia`

   `installkernel("Julia")`
4. At this point launch the notebook from the command line

```
jupyter notebook --browser="brave"
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem when I tried to add IJulia:

```
   julia > using Pkg
   julia > Pkg.add("IJulia")
```

This produced similar errors to what you posted. My solution was to  remove the .julia directory in my home directory:

```
   $ rm -rf ~/.julia
```

Then I restarted julia and proceeded to install IJulia using the commands above, and it worked.